# Getting pydbg working on windows 10

Tags: tools, debuggers, python

I downloaded the paimei tool and dropped the pydbg package files inside .../paimai/pydbg then installed paimei but I can't seem to get pydbg to work. I keep getting an error with pydasm when trying to import pydbg. Any tips?

I have python 2.7 on windows 10.

Comment: what error? we can't see your screen from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you installed `pydasm` properly? `pydasm` cannot be automatically installed by `pip`, so most installations of dependent software will just assume it is installed when in their own installation process as well as when executing.

[This](https://github.com/OpenRCE/sulley/wiki/Windows-Installation) explains how `libdasm` and `pydasm` can be compiled and installed on windows. [This](http://www.securityaddicted.com/2014/02/07/howto-setup-debugging-reverse-engineering-environment-python-tools/) provides a prebuilt package and shows how to properly install it, together with additional scripts you seem to be using.

It is not too clear from your question, but it might be the case that the missing package is `pydbg`, depends on how I interpret your text.
If that's the case, the second aforementioned link also describes how `pydbg` can be installed, and additionally google is your friend.

If these links does not work, providing the output of `pip freeze` will be a good start of additional info.

Comment: Sorry for the vague question I was at work when I posted it and didn't have my personal laptop on me. I deleted everything and followed the steps in the second link you posted and it worked! Must have been the old pydasm.pyd file that came with pydbg.

Comment: no worries, glad I could help :)